# How to launch a location settings task on wp8？

Tags: windows-phone-8

I noticed that one app named quick-settings has a feature which can launch location settings task（see the below link）， but I can‘t find the task in wp8 API list，can you tell me what is it？

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/quick-settings/2a2cbaa7-6d75-420c-ae14-2339618da43e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for question is not clear, now I got the answer, here it is:

```
var op = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-location:"));
```

Thanks all the same!!